# PHP not getting User data from database when data is already in database

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code ! PHP not getting User data from database when data is already in database ! Help me , i am stuck. When i Enter details in login.php it redirects me to login.php?invalid=1 and shows error of incorrect information or session expired ! Despite the information is same !

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include_once("include\config.php");
    $login = $_POST["textfield1"];
    $pwd = $_POST["textfield2"];
    $recordset = mysql_query("select * from users");
    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($recordset)){
    if($login == $record["ulogin"] && $pwd == $record["upassword"]) {
        $_SESSION["ulogin"] = $record["ulogin"];
        $_SESSION["uid"] = $record["uid"];  
        if($record["utype"] == 1){
                $_SESSION["utype"] = $record["utype"];
                header("Location:admin.php?uid=".$record["uid"]);
                exit;
        }else{
                header("Location:home.php");
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
    header("Location:login.php?invalid=1");
?>
```

Comment: You appear to save passwords in plain text. Please do not do that. Also please note that the `mysql_` functions are deprecated and should not be used any longer. Use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed 
From :

```
include_once("include\config.php");
```

To :

```
include_once("include/config.php");
```

AND

From :

```
><?php 
session_start();
```

To :

```
<?php 
    session_start();
```

AND

From :

```
$recordset = mysql_query("select * from users");
```

To :

```
$recordset = mysql_query("select * from users WHERE username = "'.$login.'" AND password = "'.$pwd.'");
```

Please replace your code with this code and try. Hope this will help you.

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once("include/config.php");
$login = $_POST["textfield1"];
$pwd = $_POST["textfield2"];
$recordset = mysql_query("select * from users WHERE username = "'.$login.'" AND password = "'.$pwd.'"");
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($recordset)){
if($login == $record["ulogin"] && $pwd == $record["upassword"]) {

$_SESSION["ulogin"] = $record["ulogin"];
$_SESSION["uid"] = $record["uid"];  
        if($record["utype"] == 1){
        $_SESSION["utype"] = $record["utype"];
        header("Location:admin.php?uid=".$record["uid"]);
        exit;
        }else{
    header("Location:home.php");
    exit;
    }
 }
} 

       header("Location:login.php?invalid=1");  
   ?>
```

Comment: explain what have you changed.

Comment: Yes, you should explain the change you did.

Comment: I have done it. Sorry for my mistake and Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you then give it right so it will be helpful to other users too

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408037/php-not-getting-user-data-from-database-when-data-is-already-in-database
    include_once("include/config.php");
    $login = $_POST["textfield1"];
    $pwd = $_POST["textfield2"];
    $recordset = mysql_query("select * from users WHERE ulogin = "'.$login.'" AND upassword = "'.$pwd.'"" ");
    $num_row_user =mysql_num_rows($recordset);
    if($num_row_user>0)
    {
       while($record = mysql_fetch_array($recordset))
       {
         if($record["utype"] == 1) 
         {
            $_SESSION["ulogin"] = $record["ulogin"];
            $_SESSION["uid"] = $record["uid"];
            $_SESSION["utype"] = $record["utype"];
            header("Location:admin.php?uid=".$record["uid"]);
            exit;
         }
         else
         {
            header("Location:home.php");
            exit;
         }
       }
    }
    else
    {
       if (mysql_errno()) 
       { 
          header("Location:login.php?invalid=1&message=QueryError");
       }
       else
       {
          header("Location:login.php?invalid=1&message=invalid username and password");
       } 

    }
```

1. You have to check the file path of the config file 'include\config'
   changed to   'include\config'.
2. and have to check your db connections in include/config.
3. no space before the session_start()
4. and change your coding style because its arise the more performance
   issue. and use the following coding style to reduce the
       performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change `include_once("include\config.php");` to `include_once("include/config.php");`

Answer (score 0):

Include your `config.php` file like this :

```
include_once("include/config.php");
```

It can't be like this :

```
include_once("include\config.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below Query

```
select * from users WHERE username = "'.$login.'" AND password = "'.$pwd.'"
```

then you need not to loop all records again and again.

And please make sure database table has record.

Answer (score 0):

**There is a problem in including database configuration file.**

**Repalce**

```
include_once("include\config.php");
```

**With**

```
include_once("include/config.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not be using the mysql_ library - it is deprecated. Please convert to either mysqli_ or PDO
2. `include_once("include\config.php");` should be `include_once("include/config.php");`
3. The query `select * from users` is likely to return a hugh number of records. A better query would be something like:

   mysql_query("select * from users where ulogin = '" . mysql_real_escape($login) . "' AND "upassword = '" . $pwd . "'");

This should return either a row or no rows at all. Save scanning the whole users table